# How to retrieve info from MySQL using JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm practicing using JSON but seems it's not retrieving the info intended.

The page shows the user details from database using JSON directly on the HTML output.

getjson

```
</p>
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "host";
$mysql_db_user = "user";
$mysql_db_password = "pass";
$mysql_db_database = "db";

$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password,
 $mysql_db_database);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$var = array();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$var[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"users":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

and in showjson

```
</p>
<table class="mGrid" id="jsondata">
<thead>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Location</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var url="getjson.php";
$("#jsondata tbody").html("");
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.users, function(i,user){
var newRow =
"<tr>"
+"<td>"+user.id+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.name+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.age+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.gender+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.location+"</td>"
+"</tr>" ;
$(newRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
});
});
});

</script>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

database users with id,name,gender,location

Comment: Can you provide some output? What is an expected value, and what is a received value?

Comment: its not getting data

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. View getjson.php directly in your browser. What do you see? (It looks like you have some extra junk on the end of the output. Is that a copy/paste error here, or is it actually in your script?)

Comment: It is not good practice to render your JSON strings manually. Consider swapping `echo '{"users":'.json_encode($var).'}';` for `echo json_encode(array('users' => $var));`. That will ensure that PHP does all the encoding for you - much less risky.

Comment: Thanks @Second. Mukesh, you will need to ask your host to change your database credentials now (or do it yourself if you can).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing `<p style="text-align: justify;">` on your JSON which renders it invalid so it will not parse.

Remove it.

---

You should have examined the data you got back from the PHP (either by accessing it though your browser's developer tools Net tab or accessing the URL directly). You could have then tested the JSON with a tool like JSON Lint.

---

PHP will, by default, claim that anything it outputs is HTML. While your use of `getJSON` will tell jQuery to ignore that and parse it as JSON anyway, best practise would be to include `header("Content-Type: application/json");`.

Best practise would also be to generate all your JSON using `json_encode` instead of wrapping `{"users":` and `}` around it with string concatenation.

Comment: please am new to json can you give me the code so that it can show up in restclient addon in highlight section